# how to compress html string on php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to compress string on PHP? For instance I have PHP function called `form_dropdown()` which return into:

```
<select name="selecOP" id="selecOP">
<option value=" ">Select selecOP</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
</select>
```

Then I call the php function to JavaScript:

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {

        counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><?php echo form_dropdown("selecOP' + counter + '"); ?></td>';
        cols += '<td><textarea name="price' + counter + '" rows="1px" cols="50px"></textarea></td>';

        cols += '<td><button class="ibtnDel btn btn-xs btn-danger"></i> Delete</button></td>';
        cols += ' </td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });
```

My problem is the browsers returns an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` . I tried it manually with straight format and it works but with block format it give me an error.

Expected output:

```
<select name="selecOP' + counter + '" id="selecOP"><option value="1">test1</option><option value="2">test2</option></select>
```

Comment: PHP doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "compress string"? Did you mean "interpret php code"?

Comment: You can't execute php using javascript. `cols += '<td><?php echo form_dropdown("selecOP' + counter + '"); ?></td>';`

Comment: @Bergi just like a javascript compressor. all string words are inline

Comment: @Jeemusu so what are some possible solution? any suggestion?

Comment: @mapet: Jeemusu suggests to use a javascript function, not a PHP function to return that markup.

Comment: @mapet: So you want to "remove all linebreaks"? You'd better go with simply escaping them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines

Comment: That's not what javascript minification does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JavaScript function you have this function call:

```
$("#addrow").on("click", function () {
```

And within that JavaScript function you have this code snipet:

```
cols += '<td><?php echo form_dropdown("selecOP' + counter + '"); ?></td>';
```

That is completely wrong. JavaScript is a browser-based language. PHP is server based; it’s a hypertext pre-processor. As explained [in the official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatcando.php):

> Server-side scripting. This is the most traditional and main target
>   field for PHP. You need three things to make this work. The PHP parser
>   (CGI or server module), a web server and a web browser. You need to
>   run the web server, with a connected PHP installation. You can access
>   the PHP program output with a web browser, viewing the PHP page
>   through the server.

Meaning that for PHP to work it must be stored on a web server, and then when the page is requested Apache—via the PHP component—runs the PHP script which does something. Either outputs content to a web browser or does something else on the server side of things.

When you do what you are doing in your JavaScript all that happens is you place raw, unprocessed PHP code in the client browser window. It does nothing.

So you need to refactor your code to perhaps use AJAX calls to allow JavaScript to communicate to the server & run the PHP code. But as-is, this code will not work as you describe for any reason. It needs refactoring.